# how to load multiple tables via API in qlikview

Tags: qlikview

We are trying to create QVD by loading data through API. We are using QVSource web-connector.. Our custom API currently provides 2 tables (Customers & Orders)

When we connect QV Source and chose, JSON TO TABLE.. it is only showing first table and only creates load script for the first table.

How can I make QV Source produce load script for more then one table?

I am also using Fiddler web debugger which shows that the API in-deed is fetching 2 tables..

Screenshot attached.

[image]

Comment: can you add quick example how the api look like and screenshot from qvsource?

Comment: I think the title is misleading, because it is a QV-Source problem. Maybe "how to load multiple tables via API in qlikview with QV-Source"